# nodejs+selenium-driver NoSuchElementError & StaleElementReferenceError

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I am doing a test based mocha. **node v8.2.1**, **selenium-webdriver: ^3.5.0**.

```
test.it('demoClass', () => {
  driver.classes[0].findElement(By.css('.class-avatar')).click();
  driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.css('.anticon.anticon-plus'))));
  //driver.sleep(2000);
  driver.findElement(By.css('.anticon.anticon-plus')).click();
})
```

I am getting two different types of errors, either its `NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:` or `StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

But whichever error, its refer to line:

> driver.findElement(By.css('.anticon.anticon-plus')).click();

When I use `driver.sleep(2000)`, its getting resolved. In my opinion, It's the question of animation. I can get the element(`.anticon.ancicon-plus`) only at the time, the page's animation is completed.

what I am confused is that I use `driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible())` without an error, It's obvious that I got the element. but at the next line, I can't use it. Or `NoSuchElementError`, or `StaleElementReferenceError`.

I find some answer like `http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225997/stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document`. But It can't help me.

Answer (score -1):

when use `driver.findElement`, something terrible will be triggered. use javascript instead it.

```
driver.executeScript(function() {
    while(true) {
        if(!document.querySelector('.anticon.anticon-plus')){}
        else {
            document.querySelector('.anticon.anticon-plus').click();
            break;
        }
    }
    return true; // not neccessary
})
```

Comment: It really help me. I don't know what selenium-webdriver does, But this method by javascript is valid. I run it without the terrible errors. [Fixing the flake](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/pull/1371), when use a frame like angular, react...,It may be hava a re-render when you do something or when the page is loaded. at the time, selenium-webdriver will give us a error. however, the javascript is still useful. @JeffC