# How to solve stale exception in selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have tried fluent wait but Actually Sometime run successfully and sometime's got exception like stale exception in selenium.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225997/stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Stale element exception arises when the element is either deleted from DOM or the element is longer attached to DOM.

You can handle through the below ways:
1).using try catch block like below:

if the element is located for the first time itself then it breaks and comes out of the loop

```
for(int i=0; i<=2;i++)
{
 try
{

 driver.findElement(By.("__")).click();

  break;
```

}
  catch(StaleElementException e))

{

```
Sysout();
```

}

}

2.You can also use webdriver wait and provide your conditions like below:

```
 WebDriverWait wait=new WebdriverWait();

 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.___());
```

Comment: I also applied these two option but getting same issue in my code.

Comment: Could you share the code

Comment: public void WebElement getElement(final By locator, WebDriver driver) {
  FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(100))
    .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(600)).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
  WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {

   @Override
   public WebElement apply(WebDriver arg0) {
    return arg0.findElement(locator);
   }

  });

  return element;
 }

Comment: this is my common method with fluent wait and getting sometime stale exception and some time work fine.