# Registration bot

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Hi i would like to write registration bot.

I am using selenium with python and at the beginning I have encountered following problem.

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
    for elem in elems:
        elem_ = elem.get_attribute("href")
        regex = re.compile('signup')
        match = re.search(regex, elem_)
        if match:
            print(elem_)
            elem.click()
```

with that i am able to find registration link, but when i try to click it it gives me:

```
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

am i badly accesing the element? how to execute click function on element from list created by find_elements_by_something?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are executing the *click* function is correct: the *find_elements* function return a list of [WebElements](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) and you call the *click* function of one of its elements.
The problem resides elsewhere.

Docs:
[Stale Element Reference Exception](https://www.selenium.dev/exceptions/#stale_element_reference)

> A stale element reference exception is thrown in one of two cases, the
>   first being more common than the second:
>
> The element has been deleted entirely.
>
> The element is no longer attached to the DOM.

As you can see the exception is thrown the moment selenium is unable to locate the element int the DOM structure.

A generic solution to this problem does not exists as it depends on the web page you are working on.

Generally this kind of problems occurs in *dynamic pages* where, as the name implies, the DOM structure is generate dynamically.

As simple it may seems a [common solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225997/stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document) is to try again, just surrounds it in a **try** block and re-execute the code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

try:
    ...
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    ...
```

In the worst case scenario, if the only action that you have to perform is the button click(), you could work-around the DOM moving to an element by coordinates, via an [ActionChain](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html).

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

elem = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body')
ac = ActionChains(driver)
ac.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(x_offset, y_offset).click().perform()
```