# EXCEPTION: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver4

My HTML-Page contains (among other stuff) this bit:

```
<ol id="links">
<li id="links_1"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a></li>
</ol>
```

In my code to test the page, I then do:

```
el←FindElementById'links_1'
(ACTIONS.MoveToElement el).Build.Perform
```

and this crashes with

```
EXCEPTION: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
```

However, this error doesn't seem to be justified, as the element is still alive:

```
      el.Displayed
1
      el.Text
stackoverflow
      el.Location
{X=56,Y=282}
```

How can I fix this problem?

(The environment is APL. I've left out a few APL-details here because I feared they might be avoidable "distraction" from the core-issue)

During my research before posting, I saw the question [stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225997/stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document) but it doesn't seem to apply:

- as shown, I'm doing the `FindElementById` and access it immediately after finding it. The DOM doesn't change, page is static.
- explanations about it no longer being part of the DOM do not apply: it is found and, as I attempted to show, I can access properties such as `Displayed` or `Text`.

I also went through the [reference](https://www.selenium.dev/exceptions/#stale_element_reference), but this explanation did not help.

Also, there is no looping going on and nothing changes the page. It's really straightforward: GoToUrl * Find * MoveToElement.

I removed the chromedriver-tag, as I can repro this with Firefox and geckodriver. However, with geckodriver, I get "EXCEPTION: Web element reference not seen before:" when I do `MoveToElement` - but I can do `el.Click` and access its properties in exactly the same way that as with Chrome.

**Update**: a coworker investigated this a bit deeper (beyond my comfort zone) and found that before throwing this "stale exception", there is (I'm not sure how to word this properly and where exactly it occurred) a 404-exception. I just know 404 as an HTTP Status-code - that's all it means to me. But clearly the browser was not asked to navigate anywhere, so I can't be related to an HTTP404. Does that perhaps ring some bells with anyone more familiar with the internals of WebDriver?

Comment: `links_1` (with an **s**) != `link_1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225997/stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document)

Comment: @SiKing: sorry, that was a stupid typo in the question. The actual code refers `links_1` - otherwise it wouldn't be found and expose the attributes I've shown.

Comment: @Fenio: I saw that reply before posting - but the solutions suggested there do not seem to apply. I'll edit the question and add a discussion of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a complex and multi-layered problem, but when I finally removed all layers - it worked!
The key-factor which caused this problem:

- due to a fault in the way I had written the test caused it to be executed twice - and the 2nd run always exposed the problem.
- I had instantiated `ACTIONS` in the test-framework and was not aware of a critical feature: it continuously  builds a chain of actions, any Build.Perform..-steps just added to that. Solution: create separate instances of every run (possibly, since it's fairly lightweight) or call `ACTIONS.Reset`(requires WebDriver4). I've never had issues with WD4 (although it still is in alpha) - but this gave the ultimate reason to switch!