# Angular link not clicking on element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, hyperlink

I have a link that shows through inspect code as below:

```
<span _ngcontent-wvt-c48="" xpath="1">
Email
</span>
```

I tried the xpath:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//span[contains(text(),'Email')]")
```

But it is not working for Selenium Java. It has been little frustrating not able to click on that and Error displayed is:

> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.

Comment: This is the link <span _ngcontent-wvt-c48="" xpath="1">Email</span>

Comment: May can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225997/stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document/54230335#54230335