# VBA Selenium : StaleElementReferenceError stale element reference: stale element not found Error

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am really new learning VBA. I am trying to make a project which scroll the website till find a specific image and close the browser. But after first loop (after closing browser) it throws StaleElementReferenceError . I tried to understand what is the reason and how to solve it but could find the solution. Here is my full module

```
Option Explicit

Dim cd              As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub FindImage()

Dim userRowNum  As Integer
Dim userslastRow As Integer
Dim productRowNum As Integer
Dim productlastRow As Integer

Dim email       As String
Dim password    As String
Dim productURL  As String
Dim buttonXPath As String
Dim imagebuttonXPath As String
Dim searchWord    As String
Dim srcLink    As String


Dim FindBy      As New Selenium.By

' Find the last row with data in Column A
userslastRow = Sheets("Kullanicilar").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
productlastRow = Sheets("Urunler").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through each row to extract email and password
For userRowNum = 1 To userslastRow
    Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    cd.AddArgument "--incognito"
    
    cd.Start
    cd.Get "example.com"
    
    cd.Refresh
    
    cd.Window.Maximize
    Call RandomNumber.GenerateRandomNumber
    cd.Wait RandomNumber.RandomNumber

    
    email = Sheets("Kullanicilar").Cells(userRowNum, 1).Value
    
    password = Sheets("Kullanicilar").Cells(userRowNum, 2).Value
    
    cd.FindElementById("login-email").SendKeys email
    cd.FindElementById("login-password-input").SendKeys password
            
    Call RandomNumber.GenerateRandomNumber
    cd.Wait RandomNumber.RandomNumber
    
    cd.FindElementByXPath("//button[@type='submit']").WaitEnabled.Click
    
    cd.Wait 5000
    
    'SEARCH
    searchWord = Sheets("KelimeileArama").Cells(1, 2)
    srcLink = Sheets("KelimeileArama").Cells(2, 2)
    cd.FindElementByClass("V8wbcUhU").SendKeys searchWord
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    cd.FindElementByClass("cyrzo7gC").WaitEnabled.Click
    
    Dim xpath As String
    xpath = "//a//img[contains(@src, '" & srcLink & "')]"

    ' Belirli bir süre içinde aranan elementi bulmaya çalış
    Dim element As WebElement
    On Error Resume Next
    cd.Refresh
    Set element = cd.FindElementByXPath(xpath, 5000) ' Wait up to 5 seconds
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
    Call MouseClick.LeftClick(100, 300)
       

    Do While element Is Nothing
        ScrollPage 0, 700
 
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

        On Error Resume Next
        Set element = cd.FindElementByXPath(xpath, 5000) ' Wait up to 5 seconds
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
    
  
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
   
    If Not element Is Nothing Then
      
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        ' Elemente tıklama
        On Error Resume Next
        cd.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].click();", element
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Elemente tıklanırken hata oluştu: " & Err.Description
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
       
    Else
        MsgBox "Element bulunamadı."
    End If
    
    cd.Wait 2000
    cd.Quit
    Set cd = Nothing
    
    
Next userRowNum
End Sub


Sub ScrollPage(horizontal As Integer, vertical As Integer)

Dim script As String
script = "window.scrollBy(" & horizontal & "," & vertical & ");"
cd.ExecuteScript script

End Sub
```

I have tried to refresh more and more, wait until element is clickable and, more debugging.

Comment: What is `RandomNumber.GenerateRandomNumber` ?

Comment: It is another module that creates random numbers for waiting. I don't think that one is the problem

Comment: My thought was that a random number is not OK for a wait. You need it to be exact and controllable.

Comment: I changed every GenerateRandomNumber  to a number but still got
 StaleElementReferenceError
stale element reference: stale element not found
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.91)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19045 x86_64)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225997/stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document

Comment: What is your code now? There are still random number waits in the code above.

Comment: What is this `Call MouseClick.LeftClick(100, 300)`

Comment: I would guess that you have scrolled away from the element you are expecting to click on ...

Comment: I suggest you use explicit waits in all places. Use this VBA code `Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay: DoEvents: Next i: End Sub`

Comment: @user10186832 it is just a mouse click event to click and close a modal